# issue with phantomjs evaluate

Tags: phantomjs, evaluate

I am using phantomjs for loading some pages from a single page application,

Phantom fires up all the scripts on the page, however there is no way to tell when the page is ready to be examined. Given that some of the data is coming from external sources it is impossible to tell when all the scripts on the page finished.

Any ideas on this, I tried waitfor, however that is not a solution for my scenario since I do not know which elements I am looking for (the external source can change the data it sends)

Comment: You could  either use [Network Monitoring](http://phantomjs.org/network-monitoring.html) or check if there is any change to the dom that you can observe e.g. a progressbar, a class that is added/removed when everything is loaded ... .

Comment: How do you determine (in a normal browser) that the page has loaded?

Comment: An idea - you could check entire DOM every second until DOM is not changed for a second or two.